# Can you make autocompletion kick in automatically for C++ in VS2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, autocomplete, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and I have been wondering why doesn't the autocompletion of Visual Studio kicks in automatically every time I start typing something in C++, unlike C#.

It does show me the list member box when I use the "." or "->" operator but not when I start typing randomly. I can make it appear using alt + right arrow but it's not nearly as efficient as just displayer the list member box automatically.

Could it be because of something I did or is it like this for C++?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. It's for a WIN32 console application.

Edit : Basically, I'm wondering if there is a way to make the list member box appear right when I start typing instead of having to do alt + right arrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autocompletion in C++ is much more complicated to achieve, and Microsoft, despire improvement with each new versions, didn't nail it.

Use a plugin like Visual Assist X to get a nice working autocompletion in VC++.

Comment: But the thing is, I have the entire list if I press alt + right arrow, it there a way to make this list appear only by typing?

Comment: There is a delay of several seconds, but it's slow nevertheless. Believe me, I use VS for more than 10 years, you need a plugin to get completion work correctly in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing CTRL + Space after **->** or **.** to activate the auto completion.

Comment: What is this supposed to do? I tried it but it didn't change anything.